# How to convert current date time into time zone format using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, unix-timestamp, epoch, dynatrace

I am trying to convert the current date time into the format "2023-05-25T09:51:55" using time zone Central European Time using PowerShell but getting below error.

**Exception calling "ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId" with "2" argument(s): "The time zone ID 'Central European Time' was not
found on the local computer."
At line:2 char:1

- $startTime = [TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TimeZoneNotFoundException**
  ```

I have tried below code

**`$localDate = Get-Date
$startTime = [TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
[datetimeoffset] $localDate, 'Central European Time'
)

$dtoEST.ToString('o') -replace '.\d+(?=-)-\d+:\d+'`**

Could anyone please let me know the good and correct way to do it.

Comment: You're missing `Standard` in your code. `'Central European Standard Time'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is due to a typo in the `destinationTimeZoneId` argument, it should be `Central European Standard Time` instead of `Central European Time`:

```bash
$localDate = Get-Date
[TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
    [datetimeoffset] $localDate, 'Central European Standard Time').
    ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

When you're not sure the exact name for `destinationTimeZoneId` you're looking for you can use:

```bash
[TimeZoneInfo]::GetSystemTimeZones() | Select-Object Id, DisplayName
```

Comment: Hey @Santiago thanks when I run the above snippet which works fine but the output show `2023-05-26T11.40.30 ` so there is dots in the time instead of colon and that causing the error, could you please help.

Comment: I see what you mean, this is related to your current culture info. Try using `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture` in the `ToString` call (see the update to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell, the first thing I do is define variables and then I like to work from there.

I would do it like that:

```
$localDate = Get-Date
$targetTimeZone = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time")
$convertedTime = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTime($localDate, $targetTimeZone)

$formattedTime = $convertedTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")

Write-Host $formattedTime
```

Comment: Hey @chewbacca thanks when I run the above snippet which works fine but the output show `2023-05-26T11.40.30 ` so there is dots in the time instead of colon and that causing the error, could you please help.

Comment: Try to edit the "ToString" Part like this: ("yyyy-MM-ddTHH':'mm':'ss")

Comment: it's working, by the way why PowerShell converting the colon into dot any reason?

Comment: Its culutre relevant. Not all cultures use the same format for dates and decimal / currency values. 
This will matter for you when you are converting input values (read) that are stored as strings to DateTime. And it will matter in some other cases.